# The kernel of Schrödinger operator

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Consider one-dimensional Schrödinger equation $-\Delta+v(x)$, with $v(x)$ has a negative lower bound, is there any reference regarding the calculation of the kernel of this operator?

Comment: Presumably you mean "Schwartz kernel"?